# Logical AND dataframes together

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a series of seven dataframes with the same length.

dates1 looks like:

```
   month  day  year
0     04   20  2009
1     04   20    09
2      4   20    09
3      4    3    09
4    NaN  NaN   NaN
5    NaN  NaN   NaN
6    NaN  NaN   NaN
7    NaN  NaN   NaN
8    NaN  NaN   NaN
...
```

dates2 looks like:

```
   month  day  year
0    NaN  NaN   NaN
1    NaN  NaN   NaN
2    NaN  NaN   NaN
3    NaN  NaN   NaN
4    Mar   20  2009
5    Mar   20  2009
6    Mar   20  2009
7    Mar   20  2009
8    Mar   20  2009
...
```

and so on, up through dates7. I want to create a dataframe that merges them all together, but merge doesn't seem to be working for me.

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
alldates = pd.concat([dates1,dates2,dates3,dates4], axis=0)
return alldates.dropna()
```

And that sort of works, but it starts messing up once I add in dates5, dates6, dates7 because those dataframes have some rows with the same index values as alldates.

I'm stumped on this. What more information do I need to provide? Is there a more elegant way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe all you need is to drop the duplicate index after concatenating by keeping only the first one i.e

```
alldates = pd.concat([dates1,dates2,dates3,dates4], axis=0).dropna()
alldates = alldates.loc[~alldates.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

print(alldates)

month  day  year
0     4   20  2009
1     4   20     9
2     4   20     9
3     4    3     9
4   Mar   20  2009
5   Mar   20  2009
6   Mar   20  2009
7   Mar   20  2009
8   Mar   20  2009
```

In case you are trying to fill the nan values from other dataframes then you can use

```
adf = df.fillna(df2)
```

For more than two dataframes

```
l = [dates1,dates2]

for i in range(len(l)-1):
    ndf = l[i]
    ndf = ndf.fillna(l[i+1])
```

Comment: It works when `l = [dates1,dates2]`, but when `l = [dates1, dates2, dates3]`, the loop clobbers the values from date1 in the resulting dataframe.

Comment: Are you trying to drop the duplicates? Will the updated solution work?

Comment: the updated solution you've provided does seem to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using append like this:

```
dataframes = [dates1,dates2,dates3,dates4]
alldates = pd.DataFrame() 
for dataframe in dataframes:
    alldates = alldates.append(dataframe)
return alldates.dropna()
```

Comment: That works as well as the original solution I posted, but it still leaves me with the problem of rows with duplicate indexes. I get results that include duplicate rows, like 2 different rows with index 9 when what I want is "if there's already a row with index 9, don't append this new row with index 9."

Comment: @Bharath I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: If you use append then it adds all the rows of a dataframe to another dataframe, if he will first delete the Nan rows it should work

Comment: And if an indentical row is duplicated he can use drop_duplicates in the end